# Upload Multiple File and text using HTML form and PHP

Tags: php, image, forms, text, file

hey I'm stuck on a project since long. Well I have a Project in which user upload multiple images and add tile, description. The form is processed, the image files are stored in a folder and creates thumbnails and the same entry is added to the MySQL database. Well I have done the image processing and thumbnail generation using the "`foreach ($_FILES as $k=>$v)`". But I'm unable to get the same repeat with the text fields (Title and description). Here is the code for both "`form.php`" and "`process.php`". Please help.

**formprocess.php**:-

```
foreach($_FILES as $k => $v){
  if($_FILES[$k]['size'] > 100000){
    echo "Image size exceeded";
    return false;
  }
  else {
    $add = "../Image_Folder/".$_FILES[$k][name]; // the path with the file name where the file will be stored, upload is the directory name.
    //echo $add;

    if(!move_uploaded_file ($_FILES[$k][tmp_name], $add)){
      echo "Failed to upload file Contact Site admin to fix the problem";
      exit;
    }
    else {
      $query = "INSERT INTO Image (img_id, user_id, img_src) VALUES (NULL, '$user_id', '{$_FILES[$k][name]}')";

      $result = mysql_query($query);

      if(!$result) {
        die('Unable to upload Poster to database: ' . mysql_error());
      }
      else{
        $query2 = mysql_query("SELECT img_id FROM Image WHERE img_id = last_insert_id()") or die(mysql_error());

        while($row=@mysql_fetch_array($query2, MYSQL_ASSOC)){
          $cat_id=$row['img_id'];
        }

        ///////// Start the thumbnail generation//////////////
        $n_width = 100;          // Fix the width of the thumb nail images
        $n_height = 100;         // Fix the height of the thumb nail imaage

        $tsrc = "../Image_thumbs/".$_FILES[$k][name];   // Path where thumb nail image will be stored
        //echo $tsrc;

        if (!($_FILES[$k][type] == "image/jpeg" OR $_FILES[$k][type] == "image/gif" OR $_FILES[$k][type] == "image/png")) {
          echo "Your uploaded file must be of JPG or GIF or png. Other file types are not allowed<BR>";
          exit;
        }

        ////////////////////// Starting of GIF thumb nail creation ///////////
        if (@$_FILES[$k][type] == "image/gif")
        {
          $im = ImageCreateFromGIF($add);
          $width = ImageSx($im);              // Original picture width is stored
          $height = ImageSy($im);             // Original picture height is stored
          $newimage = imagecreatetruecolor($n_width, $n_height);
          imageCopyResized($newimage, $im, 0, 0, 0, 0, $n_width, $n_height, $width, $height);

          if (function_exists("imagegif")) {
            Header("Content-type: image/gif");
            ImageGIF($newimage, $tsrc);
          }
          elseif (function_exists("imagejpeg")) {
            Header("Content-type: image/jpeg");
            ImageJPEG($newimage, $tsrc);
          }

          chmod("$tsrc", 0777);
        }
        ////////// end of gif file thumb nail creation //////////

        //// start of png thumb nail creation ////
        if (@$_FILES[$k][type] == "image/png")
        {
          $im = ImageCreateFromGIF($add);
          $width = ImageSx($im);              // Original picture width is stored
          $height = ImageSy($im);             // Original picture height is stored
          $newimage = imagecreatetruecolor($n_width, $n_height);
          imageCopyResized($newimage, $im, 0, 0, 0, 0, $n_width, $n_height, $width, $height);

          if (function_exists("imagepng")) {
            Header("Content-type: image/png");
            ImagePNG($newimage, $tsrc);
          }
          elseif (function_exists("imagejpeg")) {
            Header("Content-type: image/jpeg");
            ImageJPEG($newimage, $tsrc);
          }

          chmod("$tsrc", 0777);
        }
        //// end of png thumbnail generation /////

        ////////////// starting of JPG thumb nail creation //////////
        if($_FILES[$k][type] == "image/jpeg"){
          $im = ImageCreateFromJPEG($add);
          $width = ImageSx($im);              // Original picture width is stored
          $height = ImageSy($im);             // Original picture height is stored
          $newimage = imagecreatetruecolor($n_width, $n_height);
          imageCopyResized($newimage, $im, 0, 0, 0, 0, $n_width, $n_height, $width, $height);
          ImageJpeg($newimage, $tsrc);
          chmod("$tsrc", 0777);
        }

        $sql = "INSERT INTO catalogue_thumb(thumbid, cat_id, thumb_src) VALUES(NULL, '$cat_id', '$tsrc')";
        $result_sql = mysql_query($sql);
        if(!$result_sql){
          echo "Sorry could not save thumbnail to database";
          return false;
        }
        else{
          echo "All Images and Thumbs Uploaded successfully";
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
?>
</blink>
```

**form.php**:-

```
$upload_image_limit = 6;
while($i++ < $upload_image_limit){
  $form_img .= '<label>Image '.$i.': </label>
                <input type="file" name="uplimg'.$i.'"><br/>

                <label for="name">Enter Prduct Name</label>
                <input type="text" maxlength="65" name="img_name"/>

                <label for="description">Add Description</label>
                <input type="text" maxlength="250" name="img_description"/>
               ';
}

$htmo .= '<form method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" action="formprocess.php">
            <fieldset>
              '.$form_img.'
              <input type="submit" value="Upload" style="margin-left: 50px;" />
            </fieldset>
          </form>
         ';
echo $html;
?>
//////////////////////////////////////////////
```

Answer (score 0):

You should change the name attribute of input text. You have done so for the file field.

```
name="uplimg'.$i.'"
```

Add $i to the names of the text-fields too.